# Finding unauthorized user in access logs

Tags: wordpress, logging

My wordpress site has some kind of virus or malware.  I clicked a link from the wordpress backend and a youtube page with russian characters opened in a new tab.  I'm no pro but that tells me with 100% certainty something is wrong. Then I got an email that a new user was added to my site with administrator privileges named "desctop".  I deleted the user, and changed passwords for all other users.  I am currently going through my logs to try to find out what is going on, I believe if I find their IP it will be easier to see all actions they carried out and undo them.

I got the email from wordpress about the new user being added @ 12:50pm so I figured I could use that time and date to see who it was but the only thing I see around that time is bingbots, google, etc.  Can anyone give some advice on how to search the logs for the point at which this new user was added?

Edit:

Found this in my logs

187.176.68.48 - - [07/Mar/2018:13:50:12 -0700] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3269 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/931B"

187.176.68.48 - - [07/Mar/2018:13:50:13 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/931B"

187.176.68.48 - - [07/Mar/2018:13:50:14 -0700] "GET /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1" 200 49309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/931B"

187.176.68.48 - - [07/Mar/2018:13:50:19 -0700] "POST /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1" 302 599 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/931B"

124.106.203.176 - - [07/Mar/2018:14:58:13 -0700] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3269 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/C43B"

124.106.203.176 - - [07/Mar/2018:14:58:15 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/C43B"

124.106.203.176 - - [07/Mar/2018:14:58:17 -0700] "GET /wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=footer.php HTTP/1.1" 200 163313 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/C43B"

124.106.203.176 - - [07/Mar/2018:14:58:48 -0700] "POST /wp-admin/theme-editor.php HTTP/1.1" 302 364291 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/C43B"

Seems they edited my footer, which isn't showing up on the site at the moment.

Comment: You can reinstall Wordpress or update base files. Its basic: Go updates menu and re-update Wordpress installation in your wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

what platform or control panel you are using, and in your case in my option you need to start using security plugin like Wordfence Security which have a lot of feature to help you investigate easily and can scan your whole site to check if something wrong with your files .

Comment: I'm all self taught :/ so my vocabulary isn't great.  I am using wordpress hosted by bluehost.  I believe it is on Linux, Apache, cpanel is 62.0 (build 40).  Thanks for the info about Wordfence, I was planning on getting something like that once the site is clean.